# Why did Facebook suddenly switch from using the popup auth instead of the lightbox auth when calling FB.login from a canvas app?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authentication, facebook-canvas

Suddenly, on between 4/23/2013 and 4/24/2013, Facebook abruptly,and without notification, stopped using the iframe lightbox version of the auth dialogue for Canvas apps and replaced them with the popup version. This really screwed us over as we had to scramble to recode whole sections of javascript.

I've known for some time that the iframe version of the auth dialogue was not available anywhere but on a canvas app.

Could somebody point me to documentation of this change for canvas apps?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/360059080772901

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same issue today. The only thing we could find was https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/, but apparently, this popup-window method has been available for *games* for several weeks now.

For those who can't get the authentication dialog to pop up on loading the app, the new method uses popup-windows at all times, even when running the app as a tab on a Facebook page. The only solution I've found is to run the `FB.login` function on a click event.

And I was planning to take the day off tomorrow…

Comment: Seriously, I've got vacation tomorrow and ended up having to rewrite several functions to do that exact fix. So much for Facebook's "Developer Love"

Comment: Oh tell me about it… I had things to do before I had to pull that all-nighter. –Actually, the agency I work for runs a beta instance of our apps, so we could have prevented this by connecting it to connect.beta.facebook.net instead of connect.facebook.net.